# Programmatically generate animated gifs that show up properly on Twitter posts?

Tags: image, twitter, imagemagick, gif

I am able to utilize imagemagick to properly generate animated images and I can post them to twitter without issue, however upon posting them, it seems as though Twitter is somehow destroying the animation component I'm guessing with it's reencoding of the image.

This is less than desirable in my situation as I need to post a statistical compilation of images daily to an account and need the animation to retain integrity.  I am supposing that this is a function of Photobucket that they're now using or such.

How does one encode an image and upload it such that it retains its integrity?  I have wondered about uploading directly to TwitPic or other options or perhaps exploring more fully the imagemagick encoding options so that they line up precisely with Twitter requirements in order to produce an image that requires no reencoding, however I'm looking for help in this regard.